# Custom UITableViewCell appears invisible until click, is "offsetted" and is missing one row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have followed the tutorial written [here](http://jslim.net/blog/2013/03/22/ios-create-uitableview-with-custom-cell-programmatically/). The content that is looped by `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` should contain 3 elements.

The problems are the following:

1. all the rows are completely invisible until I click on one, then the one I clicked appears.
2. only the first two (of three) rows are shown upon click
3. the last one, which should be the first row in the list view does not appear at all,
   even when clicking.

This is the code that I have in particular:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SECTThreadCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell = [[SECTThreadCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.threadList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];
    cell.wowLabel.text = [[self.threadList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];

    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    return cell;
}
```

but, if I change it to this, it works just fine but obviously without inheriting from the custom class:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SECTThreadCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.threadList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];
    cell.wowLabel.text = [[self.threadList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];

    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    return cell;
}
```

It seems that there is some sort of problem with the loop, but I cannot really tell what it is. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    SECTThreadCell *cell = (SECTThreadCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SECTThreadCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.threadList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];
    cell.wowLabel.text = [[self.threadList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"content"];

    return cell;
}
```

If the cell is nil, try to create a new one.
For more information about `dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, see the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3a).
Regards,

Comment: tried that. the if code block is not called because cell is never nil, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are calling [tableView reloadData] on Main Thread? Any UI tasks has to be performed on main thread. Please put a breakpoint in the function and check whether it is being hit from Main Thread.

Comment: I think I am, I have a void function that does that just after viewDidLoad

Comment: Just checked with the breakpoint. It is indeed getting called by thread 1 (I guess it's the main thread)